# The Images URL's doesn't show in my Home Page

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, meteor

Am using [This bootstrap CSS design](http://startbootstrap.com/template-overviews/shop-homepage/) it works fine but the images doesn't appear. I took from [its github repository](https://github.com/BlackrockDigital/startbootstrap-shop-homepage) the css file and the index.html.

i didn't make any changes, and am using it with my meteor project. I already added twbs:bootstrap package. Are there any packages i need to add to my meteor project?

why the images doesn't appear with me?

Comment: Do you have a link to your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those images does not appear because you just copied the index the css, you are missing the rest of the assets (where images are stored). But for your own images, you shouldn't have any problem to add them.